# Can't build second Azure VM in an availability set without selecting managed disks

Tags: azure, sql-server-2014

I have an Azure availability set which I built a SQL server in without managed disks, manually creating two 2TB volumes out of 1TB volumes that get assigned. If I go to build a second in the portal also without managed disks, the option to build it in the same availability set disappears and only reappears if I select managed disks, which if I also select 4TB of disk space something under the hood in Azure automatically stripes it into a single 4TB volume. Why am I being prevented from building the second machine in the availability set unless I select this disk option>